# Can the Header "Disposition-Notification-To" be assigned 2 or more addresses?

Tags: java

I am working with JavaMail, and I want the recipient of the mail to be able to confirm if the mail arrived, for this I am using the following line of code:

```
message.addHeader("Disposition-Notification-To","Nombre1<nombre1@dominio.com>");
```

So far everything works fine, now what I want is that the confirmation can reach 2 emails, but I have not made it work. I've done this:

```
message.addHeader("Disposition-Notification-To","Nombre1<nombre1@dominio.com>; Nombre2<nombre1@dominio.com>;");
```

But it still doesn't work. I do not know if it is possible to do what I want, if my syntax is wrong, or it is not possible at all.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [RFC 3798](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3798#section-2.1), you should use a comma as separator (instead of the semicolon used in your example).

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've tried using a comma, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Separated by comma if it works, my problem was the mail client.